# How find a jar file in compile-time and run-time classpath?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

i encounter a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError and i'm finding compile-time and run-time classpath,but i don't know how to find them?
thank you!

Comment: Generally, "use Maven or Gradle".

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use the next line:  System.out.println (System.getProperty ("java.class.path"));
I hope that this could help you to find the location of the classpath

Have a nice day!